# RegEx to remove multiline property

Tags: regex, delphi, firedac

I'm porting my system to another data access library. For that, I'm using regex to replaces/remove some codes on my source. (A example above)

I need to remove everything between IBOQ_OrderingItems.Strings and ') by regex. But I can't write a regex to express this condition to express that. In my attempts, this does not recognize something like #180'asdf' or 'adsf (asdf) asdf' or ' adf '. When recognized, the regexp delete all content of file.

```
object SQLCalcula_umaLinha: TFDQuery
    IBOQ_OrderingItems.Strings = (
      'sf')
  end
  object SQLCalcula_VariasLinhas: TFDQuery
    IBOQ_OrderingItems.Strings = (
      'sfdf'
      'sdffs'
      'sf')   
  end
  object SQLCalcula_parentesesNoMeio: TFDQuery
    IBOQ_OrderingItems.Strings = (
      'sfdf'
      'sdffs ('' asdf '')'
      'sf')
  end
```

Comment: This needs an MCVE - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Amongst other things, you don't say which regex library you're using, and you haven't shown your regex or code that uses it.

Comment: I'm sorry. My English is terrible. I don't communicate very well in English. Any way, I was found a solution to my question and have posted down.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
IBOQ_.*.Strings.=.\((\s.[\w|\s|('|')|@|!|$|#||&|*|<|>|=|*|~]*.)+'\)
```

I hope to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try something like

```
IBOQ_.*\.Strings\s*=\s*\((?:'[^']*'|[^)])*\)
```

which does it in 288 steps instead of yours, that does it in 48067 steps ;)

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ryYmJe/3).

**Edit** Changed to handle parentheses inside quotes.

Comment: the last group is wrong.  The selection doesn't apply to last 'sf')
`    object SQLCalcula_parentesesNoMeio: TFDQuery
      IBOQ_OrderingItems.Strings = (
        'sfdf'
        'sdffs ('' asdf '')'
        'sf')
    end `